# Post-Archive like a page in a specific subdirectory

Tags: posts, categories, url-rewriting, archives

I have a webpage with posts which belong to specific categories (eg *projects*). I want to show the archive of a specific category like a page.

## Status quo

The site structure is similar to this:

> /
>     /our-work/
>     **/our-work/projects**  <- here I want to have the archive for *projects*
>     /xyz
>     /...

I use the following settings:

- `category_base` = *cat*
- `permalink_structure` = */news/%category%/%postname%/*

I can access the projects-archive via example.com/cat/projects.

## What I already tried

I tried the following without success:

Removing a `page_for_posts` and setting it to a newly created page "*news*".

Including the following code in the .htaccess file before the wordpress section (with and without an `[L]`: If I use `[L,r=301]` I get a 301-redirect.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/our-work/projects/$ /cat/projects/
</IfModule>
```

I think there was a time where it worked somehow, but I can not remember how I did it. (Maybe the page only showed all posts, because it had no other info).

## My Questions

1. Is there a better way to do this? How? (I think about creating a real page and wring a shortcode, that includes/displays all posts in the projects category)
2. If not - How can I do that?
3. Is it possible to have the posts of this category in this "subdirectory" like */our-work/projects/acme*?

Comment: Splitting out single category to be handled differently makes me think it might be better served by CPT or taxonomy (depending on rest of your structure).

Comment: Would that be different? AFAIK Wordpress CPT are also just posts. Could I use a cpt archive like a page?

Comment: The challenge is not it being posts, it's the elaborate condition you want to single them out (one term out of many). This is _probably_ doable, but my instinct is that changing structure might make more sense. Hard to say confidently without knowing all your information architecture.

Comment: Yes, you should use a CPT. @Tyler Carter's answer shows how to add a slug to the permalinks for the CPT. You can create an archive template specific to the post type. In the case of Tyler's code, that archive would be archive-career.php. https://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom post type with a custom slug permalink structure.

```
$args = array(
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'our-work/book' ),
);
register_post_type( 'projects', $args );
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked. I only had to add `has_archive` and `public`, see my answer below: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142269/post-archive-like-a-page-in-a-specific-subdirectory/142344#142344

Answer (score 0):

The Answer of Tylor almost worked. I had to set at least the arraykeys `has_archive` and `public` to true to use */our-work/projects/*

```
$args = array(
    'label'       => 'projects',
    'description' => 'Projects',
    'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'our-work/projects' ),
    'has_archive' => true, //so I can use /our-work/projects/ (archive)
    'public'      =>'true', //otherwise it included other posts in the archive
    'show_ui'     => true, //to see it in the admin menu
);
register_post_type( 'projects', $args );
```

I also had to call `flush_rewrite_rules()` once to update the permalink structure (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation for details).